# Call a static superclass method from inside a subclass method

Tags: ruby

Hi I am new to Ruby and I don't understand why the call to a superclass' static method doesn't work with the super keyword, I get this kind of error

```
super: no superclass method `creer_adherent' for Adherent:Class
```

This is the superclass :

```rb
   class Personne
      ...
   def self.create(type)
        print "Nom:"
        nom = gets.chomp
        print "Prénom:"
        prenom = gets.chomp
        if type == "adhérent"
            personne = Adherent.new(nom,prenom)
        else
            personne = Auteur.new(nom,prenom)
        end
        @@liste.push(personne)
        puts "#{type.capitalize} créé(e) : #{personne.nom} #{personne.prenom}"
    end
   end
```

Then the subclass:

```rb
   class Adherent < Personne
      ...
    def self.creer_adherent
       super.create("adhérent")
    end
   end
```

main.rb

```rb
   loop do
    case menu
    when "0"
      break
    when "1"
      Adherent.creer_adherent
    end 
end
```

Comment: Where do you call the `creer_adherent` method?

Comment: Sorry I completely forgot, I just edited the question

Comment: it doesn't work because `super` is not the `superclass`. `super` is trying to call a method by the same name on the `superclass` (which that class does not define such a method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have missunderstood what the `super` keyword in Ruby does and what its actually used for. `super` is used to call the method in the super class with the same name:

```
class Adherent < Personne
  def self.create
    super("adhérent")
  end
end
```

It's not a reference to to the super class. Thus when you're calling `super` you're calling `creer_adherent` on the superclass - and then you're trying to call `.create` on its return value.

If you just want to call an inherited method you just call it:

```
class Adherent < Personne
  def self.creer_adherent
    create("adhérent")
  end
end
```

If you really wanted call the method on the superclass explicitly you can:

```
class Adherent < Personne
  def self.create
    puts "This method should not be called"
  end

  def self.creer_adherent
    superclass.create("adhérent")
  end
end
```

However this isn't something you would normally do.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I changed the call to this :

```rb
def self.creer_adherent
    method(:create).call("adhérent")
  end
```

Now the problem is I have the exact same class (Livre) and its superclass (Document) but when I used the exact same code (super.create) as in the question above it didn't give me an error and worked just fine ! What would be the problem ?

Comment: You can simplify this to `create("adherent")`